# Difference between .textContent and .innerHTML using &zwnj;

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't `&zwnj;` render the same when using Javascript's `.innerHTML` and `.textContent`?

Here's example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var span = document.getElementById("spanny");
  var span2 = document.getElementById("spanny2");
  span.textContent = "randomtext&zwnj; &zwnj;morerandomtext";
  span2.innerHTML = "randomtext&zwnj; &zwnj;morerandomtext";  
}
```

```html
<span id = "spanny"></span>
<br>
<span id = "spanny2"></span>
```

And is there a way using `.textContent` to make it look like the `.innerHTML`'s example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.textContent` is specifically used for modifying the text content of an element, while `.innerHTML` is used to modify the content of the element, which may contain tags. In other words, modifying `.innerHTML` would have the effect of modifying the actual HTML code with the given value, which `.textContent` won't.

About your query regarding HTML character entities, it turns out when you use `.textContent` and set the value to something like `&amp;`, it doesn't really set the content to `&amp;`, but `&amp;amp;` i. e. It already escapes the `&` and hence it is not treated like a character entity anymore.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fixit, while still using .textContent?

Comment: In place of typing `&zwnj;`, hold `Alt` and press `0128` one-by-one in order to type the character and inserting it in `.textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML will get html tag and textContent will not, you can see the diffrent on console.

```
<span id = "spanny"><span>abc</span></span>
<br>
<span id = "spanny2"><span>xyz</span></span>
```

```
window.onload = function() {
  var span = document.getElementById("spanny");
  var span2 = document.getElementById("spanny2");
  console.log(span.textContent)
  console.log(span2.innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: I know that, but what about referrring to &znwj;

Comment: when you use textContent your data will just be a "text", but innerHTML will as DOM object.

Comment: so if you use innerHTML it just like you are coding html.